# Does deallocating an instance of a class also deallocate any memory dynamically allocated by its objects/methods?

Tags: c++, memory-management

For example, as simplified as possible:

```
class thing{
    public:
        char* arr;
        thing();
}

thing::thing{
    arr = new char[1000];
}
```

If I create a dynamically allocated instance of `thing`, then deallocate it with `delete`, will the memory that was dynamically allocated by the constructor also be deallocated, or do I have to deallocate `arr` first?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not as that class is written. You will need to declare a destructor that does `delete [] arr;` - and you should follow the rule or three (or rule of five if you add move semantics).

Comment: Or rule of zero if you follow the SRP.

Comment: I'm sorry, but where can I find the rules you're referring to?  I'm a programming student in college and haven't yet been introduced to them yet, but I'm interested to learn more.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three Here you can find them all.

Answer (score 1):

No, you will leak the allocated array. A `char*` doesn't know it's supposed to `delete` itself when it goes out of scope — it's simply pointing to that memory.

If you use the right tool for the right job though, i.e. change `arr` to be a `unique_ptr` then it will automatically know to free the memory you assigned to it once the `thing` is deallocated.